# How to unfocus button after click in Vuetify 3

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I use vuetify 3.0.0-alpha.10. This is my code:

```
<template>
  <v-card-actions flat>
    <v-btn class="yourButton">
      <v-icon size="25">mdi-home</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn>
      <v-icon size="25">mdi-star</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </v-card-actions>
</template>
```

The problem is that after click on the button focus remains there, so, it is necessary to click somewhere else to remove that focus:

[image]

I tried to add

```
.yourButton .v-btn:focus::before {
  opacity: 0 !important;
 }
```

But it seems, that this solution doesn't work in Vuetify 3. How to make button remove this focus after click?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. It is necessary to update to `Vuetify 3.0.0-alpha.12`. There focus doesn't remain on buttons after click.